# What’s the legality of creating gametes from deceased individuals?

Tags: medical

If I recall correctly, there are laws prohibiting human cloning and regulating stem cell research.

Would the creation of a gamete--say, a sperm cell--from the genetic material of a deceased person, with the permission of the deceased person, be illegal under these laws?

Comment: Those cells would still be human. Your argument would only make sense if use of the cells were prohibited only to protect the personality rights *of the donor*, but if that were the case couldn't a donor just consent?

Comment: Now this is interesting. Taking bodily material from a person counts as battery, which is illegal. However, you will not be prosecuted for this since the battery only applies to living individuals. Perhaps there are laws for the desecration of dead bodies? Either way, the estate of the dead individual may have a cause of action against you, but I cant pinpoint exactly what